# Gradle: Use a sibling subproject as plugin

Tags: gradle, gradle-plugin

I have a project with two subprobjects: `gradle-plugin` and `plugin-consumer`. I want to apply the plugin from `gradle-plugin` to `plugin-consumer`. I tried to do this:

```
// plugin-consumer/build.gradle

buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath project(':gradle-plugin')
    }
}

apply plugin: 'my.plugin.id'
```

But I was greeted with the following error:

```
A problem occurred configuring project ':plugin-consumer'.
> Cannot use project dependencies in a script classpath definition.
```

I assume this is not supported because it'd require fully building `gradle-plugin` before `plugin-consumer` can be configured.

Fortunately I can use a `fileTree` dependency to accomplish my goal:

```
// plugin-consumer/build.gradle

buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath fileTree(includes: ['*.jar'], dir: '../gradle-plugin/build/libs')
    }
}

apply plugin: 'my.plugin.id'
```

This works, but it feels like a massive hack and leads to "bootstrapping problems".

For example, I can't `clean` `gradle-plugin` because the (deleted) jar file is necessary for configuring `plugin-consumer`, which must be done to (re)build `gradle-plugin`.
Fortunately this can be avoided by **always** running `build` immediately after `clean` (in the same 'run' so to speak). This can be done manually (`gradle clean build`) or automatically (with `clean.finalizedBy(build)`). Again, this *works*, but feels like a hack.

At last, my actual question: is there a better way to do this?

**Please note that `gradle-plugin` is an independent plugin that's not only used by `plugin-consumer`, therefore `buildSrc` is unfortunately not an appropriate solution here.**

Answer (score 1):

You can publish the plugin to your local Maven repository with the [Maven Publish](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/publishing_maven.html) plugin. Then simply consume it like any other artifact.

Assuming you have something similar in your plugin project:

```
plugins {
    `maven-publish`
    `java-gradle-plugin`
}
```

Simply publish it locally:

```
./gradlew :my-plugin-project:publishToMavenLocal
```

Then in your consuming project, something like:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
    }
    dependencies {
        "classpath"("com.example:my-plugin-gav:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT")
    }
}

// apply plugin
```